# How to make a HTML section position fixed for certain scrolling period?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML structure is something like:

```
<header> ..content </header>
<section class="sec-1"> ..content </section>
<section class="sec-2"> ..content </section>
<section id="sec-3">
  <div class="item-1" style="opacity:1"> <img src="exm.jpg" alt=""> </div>
  <div class="item-2" style="opacity:0"> <img src="exm.jpg" alt=""> </div>
  <div class="item3" style="opacity:0"> <img src="exm.jpg" alt=""> </div>
</section>
<section id="sec-4"> ..content </section>
<section class="sec-5"> ..content </section>
<footer> ..content </footer>
```

When `#sec-3` will appear at the bottom like http://prntscr.com/c97u0z , then page scrolling will show `.item-2`, `.item-3` at the same place of `.item-1` inside `#sec-3`, I mean at the bottom. Then page scrolls to `#sec-4` as usual.

I've tried this way:

```
function getId(element) {
  return document.getElementById(element);
}

function scroll_effect() {
  var yPosition = window.pageYOffset,
    targetPos = getId('sec4').offsetTop - screen.availHeight;
  if(yPosition > targetPos) {
    $('.item-2').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.item-1').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.item-3').css('opacity', '0');
  }
  if(yPosition > targetPos + getId('sec3').offsetHeight - (getId('sec3').offsetHeight / 2)) {
    $('.item-2').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.item-1').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.item-3').css('opacity', '0');
  }
  if(yPosition > targetPos + getId('sec3').offsetHeight) {
    $('.item-2').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.item-1').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.item-3').css('opacity', '1');
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll_effect);
```

It made changes inner items `.item-1`, `.item-2`, `.item-3` within `#sec-4` but I can't figure out how do I stick `#sec4` on the bottom at the time of changing inner items on page scrolling.

FYI, also reverse should happen when scrolls bottom to top maintaining same manner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick #se4 to the bottom of the page, just change the CSS property of it, by jQuery.
And remove it if you want to fix another section to the bottom

```
#se4 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the overflow parameter in css.
add `width: 500px;height: 500px;overflow: scroll;` for sec-3.
you will not need any javascript code with this method.

```
    <section class="sec-1">
    ..content
</section>
<section class="sec-2">
    ..content
</section>
<section id="sec-3" style="width: 500px;height: 500px;overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="item-1" style="opacity:1">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-2" style="opacity:1">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item3" style="opacity:1">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
<section id="sec-4">
    ..content
</section>
<section class="sec-5">
    ..content
</section>
```